# Should I use Hungarian notation when coding WinAPI apps?

Tags: c, winapi

I've recently started learning Win32 API and I hate Hungarian notation (those stupid prefixes in variable names which make the code looking ugly and almost unreadable), however as you may know it is absolutely everywhere in there! And this fact causes everyone to use it in their code too to keep kind of consistency... I suppose it is stupid question but anyway, should I do so as well? Will my code look strange or wrong if I don't?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms229045.aspx

Comment: @aaaa: That's a .NET standard, so it has nothing to do with the Win32 API.

Comment: Hungarian notation is a bad idea in *C++*. But in case of C I'm not certain. "I suppose it is stupid question" It is not a stupid question... "should I do so as well" You should keep your code readable. If you can do that without hungarian notation, then you shouldn't use hungarian notation. "it is absolutely everywhere in there!" Haven't seen much of hungarian notation in opensource C programs. "strange or wrong" is too subjective. A good programmer should be able to comprehend your program as long as you try to keep it readable, maintain good function/variable names, etc.

Comment: @Steven my point is Microsoft itself discourages its usage

Comment: @aaa: Microsoft discourages its use for .NET.  This isn't .NET.

Comment: @SigTerm: Some aspects of Hungarian notation appear to be useful in C.  In particular, having a consistent way of identifying member variables and using "p" to keep track of the level of indirection.  Other aspects, such as the Systems Hungarian obsession with the actual data type, do not seem to offer much value.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: "appear to be useful in C". Which is why I said "I'm not certain".

Comment: @SigTerm: Not disagreeing, just pointing out which parts I think have some possible value, without overselling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that it's only because it's internal Microsoft coding standard. I personally use it only in the original (intented) way, and sometimes it makes sense (eg, I preffer int size_kb instead of defining type for size in kilobytes).

also check this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: I agree with this. Either use it for its intended purpose or don't use it.

Comment: I personally prefer not to put the type into the name of the variable (with exception for pointers), since the data type may change over time or the data type is not relevant in reading of the code.  In the end, the compiler doesn't care.

Comment: @Thomas: That's entirely compatible with Apps Hungarian, although it conflicts with Systems Hungarian.

Comment: +1 Very interesting article.  I was not aware of the origins and distinction betweeen Systems and Apps hungarian.

Answer (score 6):

No -- the time for HN is long past. In fact, it's a good example of a second-system type of artifact that was really obsolete before it was even invented. A long time ago, the idea kind of made sense. When most compilers did little or no type checking, a somewhat systematic method of checking types by hand was an idea that at least had enough merit to be worth considering.

That's simply not the case any more though (and hasn't been for decades now). Even C compilers actually do real type checking nowadays, and compilers for nearly all other languages do considerably more still. Even a compiler that was obsolete and mediocre a decade ago will do this job far more effectively than encoding type information into a variable name gives you a hope of doing on your own. For that matter, even assemblers now do sufficient type checking to prevent many-to-most of the kinds of problems HN was intended to help with.

Worse, people who use HN frequently seem to assume it *will* do something useful, and because of that they ignore what the compiler *could* do. As a result, they actually end up with code that's considerably worse (fragile,  borderline buggy) than if they hadn't used it at all. Huge amounts of Microsoft code display this sort of problem (e.g., DWORD getting used for all sorts of incompatible purposes, and people figuring that assigning one to another makes sense because they both have "dw" prefixes).

Worse still, code that uses HN is much less maintainable than code without it. As a prime example, look around at how much *current* code still uses an "lpsz" prefix, even though the concept of "long" versus "short" pointers was last relevant in Windows 3.1,  close to 20 years ago now. In theory, this should all have been fixed during the migration to 32-bit code ~15 years ago -- but that would require huge amounts of work editing code for essentially no benefit (since the HN is worthless anyway, having a "correct" `psz` wouldn't really be any better than the "incorrect" `lpsz`).

Comment: This is a damning argument against Systems Hungarian.  I'm not sure that it says anything about Apps Hungarian.

Comment: It is useful when you have a variable, handle and ddx_link all associated with the same widget to have m_blah, c_blah and h_blah. Of course this tells you more about the joys of windows/MFC design!

Comment: @Steven: HN is one specific notation. Other prefixes simply aren't HN at all. @Martin: prefixes like "m_" for class members simply aren't HN at all. I don't think they're very useful either, but their utility (or lack thereof) is orthogonal to the utility of HN (if any).

Comment: @Jerry: With all due respect, there are two branches of HN, and the one that's closest to Simonyi's original is Apps.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/06/22/162629.aspx

Comment: I would have completely agreed with all this if you had pitched it when I first learned of Hungarian.  But I quickly grew to see it as a very consistent easy-to-use and easy-to-read naming scheme.  When properly used, it's not about creating a second type system.  I miss it dearly now that I'm in a non-Hungarian shop and I struggle to read these loooong variable names that don't express what the data is nearly as precisely.

Comment: @Adrian: When I code C++, which isn't nearly as often as I like, I still do use (Apps) Hungarian.  For C#, though, the benefits don't outweigh the costs.

Comment: @Steven:  I wasn't disagreeing with you.  I was disagreeing with Jerry.  The question is about C, not C++ or C#.

Comment: @Steve: IMO, Hungarian Notation is exactly what Charles Simonyi defined it to be. See: http://cpp.snippets.org/code/hungnote.txt. With all due respect, I think hijacking the name to refer to something else is a lousy idea (just about as bad an idea as HN itself).

Comment: @Jerry: You'll have to explain what you mean by hijacking.  Are you saying that Systems Hungarian doesn't qualify as Hungarian?

Comment: @Adrian: I wasn't disagreeing with you, either.  I guess that means we'll just have to agree to agree.

Comment: @Steven: Well, *perhaps* I should explain further, but I've already devoted a lot more time to this than I think it's worth...

Comment: @Jerry: Well, that's entirely up to you.  You are in no way obligated to endlessly answer my follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2):

### **NO!!!**

Comment: Wow, those are excellent reasons.  I can't argue with that logic.

Comment: Now tell us how you *really* feel.

Comment: I *used* to like H.N. a lot a *long* time ago, but today I couldn't agree more with you. Anyhow, a bit more reasoning would be more useful than caps and bold face.

Comment: I think this question already has plenty good detailed answers. Sometimes adding a little humor has more value than avoiding downvoters. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on a larger team that has adopted a coding convention (HN or not), then **follow it**, even if you hate it (with one exception described below).  If you're just coding for yourself, or you're on a team that has a more *laissez faire* attitude towards style, then go with what makes life easier for you.

The problem with coding conventions (especially something as artificial as HN) is that *everybody* has to follow them; if only half the team bothers to use HN properly, then nobody gets any benefit out of it at all, and you've just made your code harder to read for nothing.

Having said that, *do not* follow the idiotic convention of prefixing integer variables with `i` or strings with `lpst`; the sooner that bit of silliness dies off, the better.  HN was intended to convey more abstract semantics; the goal was to identify which objects were safe or appropriate to use for a particular operation (the Joel on Software article linked to by ruslik makes a pretty good case for it).  IOW, variable names should denote *usage*, not *type*, and HN was an attempt to codify usage.

Personally, I prefer using meaningful English (or native language of your choice) names that tell you explicitly what you're dealing with, rather than some artificial coding scheme; going from Joel's example linked above, I'd just use names like `rawName` and `encodedName` as opposed to `usName` and `sName`.  It conveys much the same semantic information, and it reads better as well (IMO, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

[Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) has a fantastic article explaining why
(a) you SHOULD hate the Hungarian you see in windows Apps, and 
(b) why you should seriously consider using it.

If you are developing in C, the flavor of notation called Apps Hungarian is indispensable and will help you write *correct* code.
If you are developing in a type safe OO language like C++, you should NOT use Hungarian as its just not needed.

Comment: Arguably, it is still of value for the C-ish parts of C++.  I'm thinking specifically of being able to distinguish between ach, psz and so on.